# React flashes message before state is set in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am having an issue where the null message (`I dont have Partners`) is flashing up for a second or so before the state is set and the message changes .. Is there any way to not show it until everything is resolved?

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    const [partners, setPartners] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getPartners() {
            await axios.get('/api/partners').then(response => {
                setPartners(response.data.data);
            })
        }

        getPartners();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <>
            {partners?.length ? <div><p>I have Partners</p></div> : <div><p>I dont have Partners</p></div>}
        </>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Create a `isFetching` state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to achieve such a thing the simplest one is to use another state to indicate the HTTP request status. Here how it is can be implemented.

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
    const [partners, setPartners] = useState([]);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState('idle');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setStatus('pending');
    
        async function getPartners() {
            await axios.get('/api/partners').then(response => {
                setPartners(response.data.data);
                setStatus('resolved');
            })
        }

        getPartners();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <>
          {status === 'idle' || status === 'pending' ?
               <LoadingComponent /> // A custom component to represent loading status
            :
             <>
              {partners?.length ? <div><p>I have Partners</p></div> : <div><p>I dont have Partners</p></div>}
             <>
          }
       </>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```